# Dictionary Different Data Types Apache Thrift

Tags: python, dictionary, types, thrift

I have a dictionary in Python. From what I understand Thrift only allows a strictly typed map `map<type1, type2>`. However, in Python values are not always of the same type.

```
dict = {'id':1,
        'text': 'some text',
        'active': None}
```

I want to pass this structure into my .thrift file

```
void submit_record(1: i32 id, 2: i32 time, 3: map<string, varying>)
```

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Thrift `union`, or a `struct`:

```
union varying {
  1 : double dbl
  2 : i32 int    // or maybe i64 
  3 : string  str
}
```

Further reading:

- [How do you say in a Thrift IDL that a client should include exactly one of a set of fields in a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923120/how-do-you-say-in-a-thrift-idl-that-a-client-should-include-exactly-one-of-a-set)
- [THRIFT-409](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-409)

Comment: That will allow me to use dictionaries that have varying values? Such as my example dictionary above.

Comment: Yes, that's why I named the union `varying`, right after your example. It could of course also have any other name. Every union has only one field set. That's the current value.