# How to determine the type of thrift message?

Tags: java, thrift

I have a pipeline that has two kind of thrift message coming in

I can try deserializing each individually and see if it runs into error

```
TDeserializer deserializer = new TDeserializer(new TSimpleJSONProtocol.Factory());

try {
   Type1Msg t1 = new Type1Msg();
   deserializer.deserialize(t1, json, "UTF-8");
   return t1
} catch() {

}

try {
   Type2Msg t2 = new Type2Msg();
   deserializer.deserialize(t1, json, "UTF-8");
   return t2
} catch() {

}
```

Is there a idiomatic way of achieving deserializing multiple message type in thrift?

Comment: I've never used Thrift, but a quick perusal of the Javadoc suggests you want a `TUnion`

Comment: ..but its abstract and constructor is protected ;(;(;(and has very poor javadoc)

Comment: if, you *knew* the (message) class name, you could do `TBase obj = (TBase) Class.forName(className).getConstructor().newInstance();` [like here(eof)](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=pinterest%2Fsinger%2Fsinger-master%2Fsinger%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fpinterest%2Fsinger%2Ftools%2FThriftLogDumper.java) ..but you probably don't!(?)

Comment: different approach: Why do you have (only) one pipeline(/endpoint) for two message types!? ;) (if you cannot infer from the "endpoint", check the option to infer it from the "message/payload")

Comment: ..and what do you do with `t1` and/or `t2` respectively?

Answer (score 0):

I answered it for Python already [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578974/dictionary-different-data-types-apache-thrift/38586448#38586448), but in fact the topic is language-agnostic.

Use a Thrift `union`, alternatively a `struct` with non-required fields will also work:

```
union varying {
  1 : Type1Msg msg1
  2 : Type2Msg msg2
  // room for more 
}
```

Further reading:

- [How do you say in a Thrift IDL that a client should include exactly one of a set of fields in a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923120/how-do-you-say-in-a-thrift-idl-that-a-client-should-include-exactly-one-of-a-set)
- [THRIFT-409](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-409)